# CakePHP Set::extract with a special character in the condition

Tags: cakephp, escaping, set, extract

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Unit] => Array
            (
                [Unit] => ST109347005
                [SplitCnt] => 0
                [UWin] => 
                [Unit>Part] => MOLDTOOLREPAIR
                [Unit>UK1] => MOLDSHELF1
                [Unit>UK2] => 28149813MH001
                [Unit>UK3] => MOLDTOOL
            )

    )
...
```

And would like to extract array of the serials stored in 'Unit' (ex: ST109347005) like this

```
$newarray = Set::extract($data,'/Unit[Unit>UK1=MOLDSHELF1][Unit>UK3=MOLDTOOL]/Unit');
```

Which doesn't work because the > is a reserved character.  I'm not sure what the syntax would be to allow this to work.  I image it would be something like this (which doesn't work)

```
$newarray = Set::extract($data,'/Unit[Unit\>UK1=MOLDSHELF1][Unit\>UK3=MOLDTOOL]/Unit');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In then end it boils down to `Set::matches`, which will receive `Unit>UK1=MOLDSHELF1` as the condition, and evaluate it using a regular expression. Escape characters are not supported, so `match` will treat the `>` as the operator, and consequently it will fail.

You'll need to rename the keys, at least temporarily for extraction, however when you're already iterating over all the entries you could easily compare the keys manually and skip the renaming and the extraction via `Set::extract`. Ideally you should rename the keys permanently.

Comment: That is how I temporarily solved the problem, just replaced the > with an _.  However I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  I did some reading on xpath and thought maybe &gt; would work, but no.  Neither did \x3e.  Oh well, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that after extracting the values and the operator from your condition, `Set::matches` will compare the left and right hand values using simple boolean operations, ie using `==`, `>`, `<`, etc. That's why not even RegEx compatible substitute chars are working.